# change text on one of the two div elements using jquery

Tags: jquery

how i can change the text (TEXT1) on the element with **a href="#ajax/test1**

```
   <div class="stats-desc"><a href="#ajax/test1">TEXT1<i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></a></div>

    <div class="stats-desc"><a href="#ajax/test2">TEXT2<i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></a></div>
```

y tried this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

$(".stats-desc").attr('a[href$="#ajax/test1] a').text("NEW TEXT");

});
```

Comment: Looks like a double-quote is missing after test1 in the selector reference, the outer single quotes are ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".stats-desc a[href$='#ajax/test1']").text("NEW TEXT");
```

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

$('.stats-desc a[href$="#ajax/test1"]').text("NEW TEXT");

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="stats-desc"><a href="#ajax/test1">TEXT1<i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></a></div>

    <div class="stats-desc"><a href="#ajax/test2">TEXT2<i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></a></div>
```

Comment: works but now i have a menu in the left that have this too "#ajax/test1  so it got changed too, i just need one

Comment: Edited my answer. Please check now

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the `a[href$="#ajax/test1"]` into your selector:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.stats-desc a[href$="#ajax/test1"]').text("NEW TEXT");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="stats-desc"><a href="#ajax/test1">TEXT1<i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></a></div>

<div class="stats-desc"><a href="#ajax/test2">TEXT2<i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></a></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `each` function to change text as

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.stats-desc a').each(function(index, item){
    if($(item).attr('href') == "#ajax/test1") $(item).text("NEW TEXT");
  });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.stats-desc a').each(function(index, item){
    if($(item).attr('href') == "#ajax/test1") $(item).text("NEW TEXT");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="stats-desc"><a href="#ajax/test1">TEXT1<i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></a></div>

<div class="stats-desc"><a href="#ajax/test2">TEXT2<i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></a></div>
```